# AWS S3 bucket connection 403 error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);

    S3Object object = new S3Object();
    object.setBucketName(existingBucketName);
    String keyName             = (storePath + "/" + file.getName()).replaceAll("//", "/");
    object.setKey(keyName);

    List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
    log.debug("Step 1 Start");
    // Step 1: Initialize.
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse =  s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
    log.debug("Step 1 End");
```

Last 3 line is throwing error like :-

```
[DEBUG][2016/10/04 12:19:17] Sending Request: POST https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com /files%2Fsns%2F201610%2FAer_24.xml Parameters: (uploads: null, ) Headers: (Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8, ) 
[DEBUG][2016/10/04 12:19:18] Received error response: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: null, AWS Request ID: 8B, AWS Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId, AWS Error Message: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records., S3 Extended Request ID: fIBtP5w=
Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 8B0B, AWS Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId, AWS Error Message: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records., S3 Extended Request ID: fIP5w=
   [ERROR][2016/10/04 12:19:18] The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 8BB, AWS Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId, AWS Error Message: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records., S3 Extended Request ID: fI5w=
```

Notes:- I am able to login to bucket by the help of cloudberry with same credintials.

Comment: when you say that you are able to login to the bucket with cloudberry, you mean that you can upload the same file as in your code to this bucket? not just list the content of the bucket?

Comment: yes I am able to upload the file through cloudberry but not through the code.

Comment: and are you sure that cloudberry also performs a multipart upload as well? What size is your file? Maybe Cloudberry uploads the file as one, and in that case you could be missing the mutlipart upload permissions. see the doc for those permissions http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html

Comment: I am uploading file of 4KB size only. not sure whether cloudberry is using multi-part upload or not.

Comment: For this size, pretty sure Cloudberry does a single part and not multipart. You should add the multipart rights as shared in the doc. You could also test with a file of few Gb size to test (Cloudberry would perform a mutlipart upload)

Comment: This certainly looks like a simple typo or copy/paste error in your accesskeyid.  The value is aphanumeric, all-caps, and typically begins with `AKIA`.  The error `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records` seems pretty unambiguous.

Comment: I think that you initiate multipart upload on line 10 but provide credentials only on line 11.

Comment: Are you using the correct region?

Comment: Yes. The region is correct and I am able to upload same file under the same bucket but different path.
Could this be a ACL issue for that path?